# I can't open Qt 4 Designer on latest Ubuntu

Tags: qt

I click the Icon, and it will flash but will not open.  Qt Creator works, but I'm trying to use Python.  I've tried remove and install a couple times, but still nothing.  I have downloaded PyQt4, Ubuntu-SDK, Qt4 (Designer, Linguist and Assistant).  I appreciate your help.

Tried `designer-qt4` , Result:

```
designer-qt4: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/designer/libqcscintillaplugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN13QsciScintillaC1EP7QWidget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the location of the file `libqcscintillaplugin.so`, and removed the file.

Or through cleaner way, better to use APT:

```
sudo apt-get remove libqscintilla2-designer
```

Now Qt4 Designer opens without a problem.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, but do you know from where did you get this file. Have you installed scintilla editor or plugin before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got the file in an add-on that came with Qt4 Designer from  the software center.  The add-on is Qt4 Designer Plugin for QScintilla2 `libqscintilla2-designer'.  P.S. I had to wait to accept my answer due to reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing qt4-default:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-default
```

Comment: Didn't seem to help, Qt4 Designer still wont load

Comment: @berrywhitex, I could not find any package that provides `libqcscintillaplugin.so`. Have you installed some thing related from a PPA? Could add output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/designer/libqcscintillaplugin.so`